# Prove $f: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R} $ is continous

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R} $ satisfy conditions:

a)function $y \to f$ is continous for every fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$

b) for every fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have function $g: x \to f(x,y)$ satisfy  $|g(x_1)-g(x_2)| \le |x_1-x_2|$

we have that $f(x,y)$ is separately continuous function but I know it's not sufficient but we have uniform continous for fixed y since it satisfy Lipshitz condition with constnt $C=1$ but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You switched from f to g in (b).

Comment: @Paul: the function $g$ is well-defined in (b): it is $g=g_y\colon x\mapsto f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** fix any $(x_0,y_0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$; then
$$\begin{align}
\lvert f(x,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \rvert &\leq \lvert f(x,y) - f(x_0,y) \rvert + \lvert f(x_0,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \rvert \\
&\leq \lvert x-x_0 \rvert + \lvert f(x_0,y) - f(x_0,y_0) \rvert
\end{align}$$